# VB.NET Login Control automatically login from another function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to force the login of an asp:Login control?

Currently when a User registers via a Formview they than have to be redirected to the Login page to sign in with their new account.  It is only using an asp:login control verified against a database table not the Membership system.

Comment: If you're not using Membership, how are you tracking whether a user is logged in or not on your pages?  Whatever provider you are using should have a Login(Username, Password) type method that you can call.

Comment: The Login.aspx page has an asp:Login control and a LayoutTemplate for username/password entry and a submit button which calls the Authenticate Method.  Authentication is set from custom code that compares inputs to database results, if matched set e.Authenticated = True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Login control is using a couple of Membership tools in the background for you.  There's a good article with details [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043613/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072005-1.aspx).

To perform the actual "login" (once you have verified the user of course), do this

```
        If userIsVerified Then
            System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, True)
        End If
```

Comment: That's great thanks, I run this immediately after verifying the signup